# How to reset personalization?

Tags: web-part, personalization

I'm trying to add a button on a page that remove any personalization.

I use this code :

```
 protected void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        WebPartManager.Personalization.ResetPersonalizationState();
        // other cleanup methods
 }
```

However, this code is failling with this error:

> The 'ResetPersonalizationState' method of 'WebPartPersonalization' cannot be called before initialization of the page is complete

What is the correct way to implement this behavior?

**[Edit]** Please note that I'm working on server side. Actually, I'm performing some other cleanup when clearing the personalizations.

I try to perform a postback after calling the `MSOWebPartPage_RestorePageDefault` but it seems that this method itself is performing a post, so my postback is ignored.

I used this code:

```
javascript:SP.SOD.executeFunc('browserScript', 'MSOWebPartPage_RestorePageDefault', function(){
    MSOWebPartPage_RestorePageDefault();
    __dopostback(...); // actually generated on the server side
})
```

But as I said, it does not works (the __dopostback is ignored as the MSOWebPartPage_RestorePageDefault itselft postback.

Answer (score 1):

To reset the personalisation you simply need to call a JavaScript on that button.

```
javascript:SP.SOD.execute('browserScript', 'MSOWebPartPage_RestorePageDefault')
```

When the user clicks the button he will be asked to reset the personalisation. Once the user confirms this the personalisations are gone.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. However, it's a bit more complicated (see my edit).